# Trying to load a page and cycle through proxies each time

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm currently trying to learn Python by doing small little silly projects to try and get my head around certain bits but I have hit a bit of a brick wall. I'm wanting to make something that will visit a page using a proxy list I have in a .txt file. I want it to load up the web page with the first proxy in the file, then load up the page with the second proxy and so on. However, I keep on getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Admin\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.6.24221\pythonFiles\ptvsd_launcher.py", line 43, in <module>
    main(ptvsdArgs)
  File "c:\Users\Admin\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.6.24221\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\__main__.py", line 434, in main
    run()
  File "c:\Users\Admin\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.6.24221\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\__main__.py", line 312, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target, run_name='__main__')
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\Admin\Documents\PythonScripts\ebay-traffic.py", line 10, in <module>
    r = requests.get(url, proxies = line)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 524, in request
    prep.url, proxies, stream, verify, cert
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 699, in merge_environment_settings
    no_proxy = proxies.get('no_proxy') if proxies is not None else None
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

The proxy file looks like this:

```
167.99.40.249:80
51.68.92.55:8080
51.83.105.113:8080
67.63.33.7:80
138.68.58.62:3128
```

I've tried various stupid things like putting the proxy file in the `int()`, but that obviously doesn't work. (I was trying a lot of silly things.)

```py
import requests

proxyList = 'proxies.txt'
file = open(proxyList, "r")
url = input('Website: ')


for line in file:
    print(line, end="")
    r = requests.get(url, proxies = line)

print('Finished.')
input()
```

I expect it to print each line of the proxy file when it loads up the page when connected to the proxy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass proxies as a dict

```
import requests

proxyList = 'proxies.txt'
file = open(proxyList, "r")
url = input('Website: ')

for line in file:
    print(line, end="")

    proxies = {'http': line.strip(), 'https': line.strip()}
    r = requests.get(url, proxies=proxies)

print('Finished.')
input()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the proxies as a `dict` to python `requests`, i.e.:

```
import requests
url = input('Website:\n')
with open('proxies.txt') as f:
    proxies = [x.strip() for x in list(f)]
for p in proxies:
    r = requests.get(url, proxies={'http': p, 'https': p})
    print(r.text)
```

---

[Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/aa4daa97d1)